# Equilibrium index in bash

Tags: linux, arrays, bash

I need to calculate an equilibrium index in bash.

> An equilibrium index of a sequence is
>   an index into the sequence such that
>   the sum of elements at lower indices
>   is equal to the sum of elements at
>   higher indices.

Consider the following input data:

```
-7#1#5#
2#-4#3#0
```

I first use the following `sed` command to change `#` into newlines and to calculate the number of elements:

```
`sed 's/#/\n/g' input.txt | wc -l`
```

This gives me the following output:

```
-7
1
5
2
-4
3
```

How can I display the value of array element after the index number, e.g.:

```
table[0] => -7
table[1] => 1
.
.
.
table[5] => 3
```

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
IFS='#'
table=( $(< input.txt) )
```

then each element can be accessed by

```
${table[0]}
${table[1]}
...
```

Comment: The number of elements is `${#table[@]}`.

Comment: ${#table[@]} command shows that table is an one element table

Comment: $ cat input.txt;
-7#1#5#2#-4#3#0
$ IFS='#';
$ table=( $( < input.txt ) );
$ echo ${#table[@]};
7

Comment: Now I wonder how to construct a loop  that will be completed when sum elements from left to right and right to left will be equal (http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Equilibrium_index)

Comment: Create another question and show us what you did with the array and what's not working

Answer (score 0):

From what you currently have, you could use `tail +n` to drop `n` first lines from a stream. Then you can read the next via `head -n1`.

Comment: Thanks but I need to sum e.g.: two first elements and compare with sum of two last elements. Tail and head for n=2 will display string with two first and two last elements. Maybe there is a way to divide this string for a single parts.

Comment: Then go for arrays as @dtmilano has suggested... or use Python or Perl instead, unless you're absolutely sure that Bash is your only option.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Thank You guys for help.

```
#!/bin/bash

cat input.txt | awk '{if($0~/^>/){print"\n"$0;next}else{printf("%s",$0)}}' > output.txt

IFS='#';table=( $( < output.txt ) );count=${#table[@]}

idx=$(( $count-1 ))

right=0

for (( i=0;i<=$idx;i++ ))
do  
    (( left+=${table[i]} ))
    if [ $left == $right ] 
      then
      echo "( EQ INDEX: $i, EQ VALUE: ${table[i]} )"
    fi
    (( right-=${table[i]} ))
done
```